# After Data Is Sent, It Is Going To A Blank Page MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on my registration page and every time I hit the submit button, it will not take my information and submit it to the database. Else, if on some occasion it does take the information, it will take me to a blank screen, when I have a header to take me to a restricted section only. Is my syntax wrong?

```
<?php
//serror_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "root"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "root"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "dfa24"); // The database name.
session_start();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){ 
    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
    or die("Failed to connect");
    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
        $regFirst = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']); // stores the name
        $regLast = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']); // the last name
        $regPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); // the password
        $regUser = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); // and username that was created.
        $sql = " SELECT loginName FROM Member
                WHERE loginName = '$regUser' "; //Double checks for duplicate usernames
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
        if($result->num_rows > 1){ // if no duplicates, creates the username.
            $_SESSION['logged']='0';
            echo "That username already exists, please choose another."; //username exists, create another one.
            $x = false;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['logged']='1';
            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Member (loginName, password, lastname, firstname)
            VALUES 
            ('$regUser','$regPassword', '$regLast', '$regFirst')";
            $result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1) or die($mysqli->error);
            header("Location: MemberHomeScreen.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        $x = false;
        $errors = array(); // all of the errors that are found below will be stored here and called later.
        $isValid = filter_var($emailaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); //checks for valid email
        $defaults = array("firstname" => "", "emailaddress" => "", "lastname" => "", "password" => "", "username" => ""); //this array stores the information that the user enters.
        $defaults2 = array("userlogin" => "", "userpassword" => "");
        if(isset($_POST['submit2'])) // Checks that the submit button has been pressed.
        {
            $x = true;
            if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) || $_POST['firstname'] === '') //Checks for the name to be filled out
            {
                $x = false;
                array_push($errors, "** Please fill in your name **");//Pushes an error
            }else {
            $defaults['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname']; //stores the item, so we do not lose it if there is an error.
            }
            if(!isset($_POST['emailaddress']) || $_POST['emailaddress'] === '') //Checks that the email field is filled out.
            {
                $x = false;
                array_push($errors, "** Please fill in your email address **");
            } else if(!filter_var($_POST['emailaddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) //Makes certain that the email is valid. I am checking for ANY and ALL valid email addresses, we can change this with preg if need be, but this seems more applicable to me.
            {
                $x = false; 
                array_push($errors,"** Please enter a valid email **");//Pushes an error

            }else {
                $defaults['emailaddress'] = $_POST['emailaddress']; //stores the item, so we do not lose it if there is an error.
            }
            if(!isset($_POST['lastname']) || $_POST['lastname'] === '') //Checks for anything in the subject line.
            {
                $x = false;
                array_push($errors, "** Please enter your last name **");//Pushes an error
            } else {
            $defaults['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname']; //stores the item, so we do not lose it if there is an error.
            }
            if(!isset($_POST['username']) || $_POST['username'] === '') // Checks to make sure there is a message in the message box.
            {
                $x = false;
                array_push($errors, "** Please enter your username **");//Pushes an error
            } else {
            $defaults['username'] = $_POST['username']; //stores the item, so we do not lose it if there is an error.
            }
            /*if(!isset($_POST['password']) || $_POST['password'] === '') // Checks to make sure there is a message in the message box.
            {
                $x = false;
                array_push($errors, "** Please enter a password **");//Pushes an error
            }*/

        }
    }
}


?>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Registration Page </title>
<link href="projects.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 id="top"> Sign In/Register </h1>
<div id="menubar"> 
<div id="menu">
<ul id="a_links">

        <li><a href="index.html">Main Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="project1.html" class="on">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactform.php">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="Resume.html">Resum&#233</a></li>
        <li><a href="membership.php">Sign In</a></li>
</ul> 
    </div>
</div><br/> 
<body>
    <?php
        $userregistration = array("firstname" => "First Name: ", "lastname" => "Last Name: ", "username" => "Username: ", "password" => "Password: ", "emailaddress" => "Email Address");
        if($x == false){
            foreach($errors as $error){ // goes through my errors and echos them in HTML.
                echo "<div class='error'> $error </div>";
            }
        }
        echo '<form action="" method="post">';
        echo '<br>';
        foreach($userregistration as $names => $label){
            echo "<div class = 'field'>",
            "<label for='$name'>$label</label>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='$names' id='$names' value=".$defaults[$names]." >";
        }
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit2'>";



    ?>
    <div id="footer">
    <p> &copy; Copyright 2013 | Email Address: Dfa24@nau.edu </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The database is accepting information now but it is just sending me to a blank page.

EDIT: Here is the page I am trying to connect to. It is a part of my directory:

```
    <?php
define("HOST", "localhost"); // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "root"); // The database username.
define("PASSWORD", "root"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "dfa24");
session_start(); 
if ($_SESSION['logged'] != '1')
{
header('Location: MemberIndex.php');
exit();
}else{
    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
    or die("Failed to connect");
    $sql = "SELECT firstName,lastName FROM Member 
    WHERE loginName= '{$_SESSION['logname']}' ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql)
    or die("Couldn't execute query");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    extract($row);
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Member's Only Page </title>
    <link href="projects.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php
echo "<div class='wrapper'>
<h1 id='top'> Welcome To Duke's Homepage </h1>
<div id='menubar'>
<div id='menu'>
<ul id='a_links'>
        <li><a href=''>About Duke</a></li>
        <li><a href='contactform.php'>Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href='Resume.html'>My Resum&#233</a></li>
        <li><a href='membership.php'>Sign In</a></li>
        <li><a href='EditMyInfo.php'>Edit Info</a></li>
</ul> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>"; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string I believe requires a mysql connection open. Since you're using mysqli this would be wrong. You should probably be using prepared statements anyhow.

Comment: I am using the same escape string on a different page and it seems to be working fine. I'll just take the escape strings off and use $_POST instead?

Comment: no, you should be using prepared statements or at least use mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: $_POST alone could be disasterous. Definitely sanitize your input, but do so in a way that's compatible with the db driver you're using

Comment: I changed it, it is sending the information to the data base but afterwards it is sending me to a blank page when I hit submit..

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: you could uncomment that error reporting line and see if you're actually getting an error. Is it taking you to MemberHomeScreen.php correctly? You're passing it as a relative URL so this would only work if MemberHomeScreen.php is in the same directory as the current page, according to the url. Also, you may want to post the contents of MemberHomeScreen.php

Comment: You can also check the output using the debugging tools of your browser to check the headers.

Comment: By the way, the check for duplicate usernames should probably have > 0 instead of 1, because when you do the check the new record has not been inserted yet.

Comment: I appreciate that, I changed it to >0. Any other suggestions out there?

Comment: Hey all, So I put the error reporting on and it said that "Warning: Cannot modify header information", I googled the problem and it was because there was an extra line before my php tag... everything seems to be working just fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I put the error reporting on and it said that "Warning: Cannot modify header information", I googled the problem and it was because there was an extra line before my php tag... everything seems to be working just fine now.